# из if сделать switch

Tags: javascript

Есть функция надо if реализовать с помощью switch

```js
 function getNumWord(num, word1, word2, word5) {
   let dd = num % 100;

   if ((dd >= 11) && (dd <= 19)) {
     return word5;
   }

   let oneDigit = num % 10;

   if (oneDigit === 1) {
     return word1;
   }

   if (oneDigit >= 2 && oneDigit <= 4) {
     return word2;
   }

   return word5;
 }
```

мой вариант

```js
function getNumWord(num, word1, word2, word5) {

  let result = '';

  switch (num) {
    case (num % 100) >= 11 && (num % 100) <= 19:
      result = word5;
      break;
    case (num % 10) === 1:
      result = word1;
      break;
    case (num % 10) >= 2 && (num % 10) <= 4:
      result = word2;
      break;
    default:
      result = word5;
      break;
  }

  return result;
}
```

чет не работает! туплю не могу понять что не так?!

Comment: потому что Вы не знаете, что такое и как работает `switch`

Comment: Какой тип выражения `num` и какой тип выражения `(num % 100) >= 11 && (num % 100) <= 19`?

Comment: num число, дело в том что тут меня путает два условия num % 100 и num % 10. если бы было  что-то одно то вопросов не было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае `switch` неудобно будет использовать, так как нет конкретных значений кейсов.

Как работает `switch`:

1. Получает значение для проверки
2. поочередно сравнивает значение для проверки со значением указанным в тест-кейсе с помощью `===`
3. если значения совпали - начинает выполнять выражения пока не встретит `break;` или `return`;

В данном случае, так как `num` число, а во всех case - boolean, всегда будет выбираться ветка default.

Для решения, в switch достаточно передавать значение `true`, в этом случае, условия будут проверяться пока хотя бы одно из них не будет иметь значение `true`.

Comment: спасибо тебе, добрый человек!!
опыта у меня маловато и есть вещи которые не до конца понимаю!!